# How to make a created class print?

Tags: java, class

This is my current code-

```
public class TriangleNumGenerator {
  int counter;
  int sides;

  public TriangleNumGenerator(){
    sides = 1;
    counter = 2

  }
  public int nextTri(){
    sides = sides+counter;
    counter = counter+1;
    return sides;

  }

  public void reset(){
    counter = 2;
    sides = 1;
  }
}

Main(){
  TriangleNumGenerator ne = new TriangleNumGenerator();
  System.out.println(ne.nextTri());

}
```

What this code was supposed to do was whenever nextTri was called then it would print "1,3,6,10" and so on.

However, the code doesn't even seem to print anything at all. How do I make this class actually run?

Comment: Add `()`. Like `System.out.println(ne.nextTri());`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ok i did that and got a new error: exit status 1
Main.java:26: error: class, interface, or enum expected
Main(){
^
Main.java:28: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  System.out.println(ne.nextTri());
  ^
Main.java:30: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
^
3 errors

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args)`. You can't change the signature of `main`. Nor can you abbreviate it.

Comment: Nor can you declare it outside a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of updates need to be done, which I have put into comments:

```
public class TriangleNumGenerator {
    int counter;
    int sides;

    public TriangleNumGenerator(){
        sides = 1;
        counter = 2;  // forgot ; here**

    }
    public int nextTri(){
        sides = sides+counter;
        counter = counter+1;
        return sides;

    }

    public void reset(){
        counter = 2;
        sides = 1;
    }

    // you forgot main method; it has to be exactly same so that JVM 
    // can find it
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TriangleNumGenerator ne = new TriangleNumGenerator();
        System.out.println(ne.nextTri());  // forgot () in nextTri
    }
}
```

These are syntactical errors. If you use any IDE, then all these should be reported!